# Turtlebot sensor defective or fine?

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, turtlebot, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Turtlebot (create base) and it' very difficult to localize it because sensors seems pretty bad. I would like to know if my Turtlebot or my data are fine or if there is a problem somewhere.

First, I cannot use directly JointState because the robot publishes always zero values. This is working only in gazebo simulation but not on the real robot. Is there some parameters to set ?

Secondly, odom sends me a angular velocity null when my robot is moving slowly even through wheels are moving (no slipping !). Encoder are on the wheel so it should be send me a velocity even with bad encoder. Does my robot encoders are defective ?

Thirdly, imu is moving itself when robot is stationary. I agree that is common for imu in position because it's a integration but I have also a velocity non null and bad results with.

I have done calibration for imu and odom, I can understand that sensors are not hight quality but what I see it's too much important to work fine. I see a lot of great videos with Turtlebot so I was wondered if these errors are normal or not.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67536/turtlebot-sensor-defective-or-fine-?/) by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2013-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide#Is_the_robot_navigation_ready.3F is a good test, especially section 2.2.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-08-07**:
I made my own tests similar to those. The result is very bad all the time. Error on orientation has a bigger impact on the position of course.
Is it possible that encoders have a low pass filter ?